# Django get client's domain name/host name

Tags: python, django, gethostbyaddr

What is the easiest way to obtain the user's host/domain name, if available?
Or is there a function to lookup the IP address of the user to see if it is bound to a named address? (i.e. gethostbyaddr() in PHP)

HttpRequest.get_host() only returns the IP address of the user.

Answer (score 5):

You can't rely on it, but you can try the [`request.META['REMOTE_HOST']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) or [`request.META['HTTP_HOST']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) from the `META` dictionary of the `request` :

> A standard Python dictionary containing all available HTTP headers. Available headers depend on the client and server, but here are some examples:

```
- REMOTE_HOST -- The hostname of the client.
- HTTP_HOST -- The HTTP Host header sent by the client.
```

Comment: +1 "You can't rely on it". That is very correct. Network configurations can mask or completely hide the IP address of the user's machine. Many places do it deliberately for security reasons, others do it due to NAT. Trying to do a reverse lookup will give some pretty bogus results as a result.

Comment: How is this distinct from `HttpRequest.get_host()`?  What address is that one reporting?

Comment: **HttpRequest.get_host()** gives you **requested** hostname. Hostname of your own website.

Answer (score 4):

You can just print `HttpRequest.META` and find what you want and I think `req.META['HTTP_ORIGIN']` is the thing you need, It's the same as the browser address bar value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`socket.gethostbyaddr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr)